# Is there a distinct command for \widowpenalty and \clubpenalty in footnotes?

Tags: page-breaking, footnotes, widows-orphans

I have found that setting `\widowpenalty=10000\clubpenalty=10000` in the main document has not prevented widows and clubs from appearing occasionally in footnotes in a long and complex document I am working on.

I eliminated those widows and clubs by adding the same commands to a new command for creating footnotes:

```
\newcommand\footy[1]
 {\footnotemark{}%
  \footnotetext{\widowpenalty=10000\clubpenalty=10000\relax#1}%
 }
```

but it seems to me that this is rather wasteful since it calls the two penalty commands over and over again. Is there, instead, a pair of commands that specify widow and club penalties for footnotes, and that only need to be called once?

Comment: BTW, end explicit numbers with a space or `\relax`. Otherwise consider, what happens, if `#1` starts with a number.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Define for example `\interfootnotelinepenalty=100` or try `10000`· Macro `\footnote` uses the given `\interfootnotelinepenalty` if a pagebreak is necessary in your footnote.

Answer (score 6):

The package `bigfoot` provides much better footnote breaking facilities than the default.  Loading it alone will often fix bad breaking issues.

By default it also defines:

```
\newcount\footnotewidowpenalty 
\footnotewidowpenalty=250  
\newcount\footnoteclubpenalty 
\footnoteclubpenalty=250  
\newcount\finalfootnotewidowpenalty 
\finalfootnotewidowpenalty=4000
```

Comment: Thanks. I looked for a while at `bigfoot`, but the documentation is scanty and I wasn't able to find many examples on-line. It seemed easier to stick with better-document packages or basic TeX and LaTeX commands.

Comment: @brannerchinese -- Sure, but all you need to do is change the settings I listed to control how bad things need to get before you allow widows and orphans in your footnotes.  Most of the other stuff `bigfoot` does is for things beyond normal footnote needs.  (Anyway, it worked for me when I changed these settings.)

Comment: I see that a lot of `bigfoot`'s functionality can be learned about by reading the comments in the `bigfoot.dtx` file, available here: http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/macros/latex/contrib/bigfoot/bigfoot.dtx