# Set \widowpenalty only in main text, not for footnotes

Tags: page-breaking, widows-orphans

I have made sort of the opposite experience than described in an older [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66011/is-there-a-distinct-command-for-widowpenalty-and-clubpenalty-in-footnotes) and the same as this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316522/how-to-set-different-clubpenalty-for-main-text-and-footnotes) without replies.
I would like to prevent widows in the main text, but I don't mind them in the footnote area when splitting of footnotes occurs. Setting `\widowpenalty=1500` patches some page breaking nicely, but due to some footnotes, unwanted white spaces appear. Is there a way to set a global option or do I have to go through my document manually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LaTeX has a mechanism for changing `\interlinepenalty` inside footnotes, but not for `\widowpenalty`.

You may try

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@footnotetext}
  {\interlinepenalty}
  {\widowpenalty 150 \interlinepenalty}
  {}{}
\makeatother
```

that would reset `\widowpenalty` to the usual value only inside footnotes, by hooking in the same place where `\interlinepenalty` is changed.

The relevant definition in `latex.ltx` is

```
\long\def\@footnotetext#1{\insert\footins{%
    \reset@font\footnotesize
    \interlinepenalty\interfootnotelinepenalty
    \splittopskip\footnotesep
    \splitmaxdepth \dp\strutbox \floatingpenalty \@MM
    \hsize\columnwidth \@parboxrestore
    \def\@currentcounter{footnote}%
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel{%
       \csname p@footnote\endcsname\@thefnmark
    }%
    \color@begingroup
      \@makefntext{%
        \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces#1\@finalstrut\strutbox}%
    \par
    \color@endgroup}}%
```

and doing something like

```
\let\oldfootnote\footnote
\renewcommand{\footnote}{\widowpenalty150\oldfootnote}
```

will *not* work, because it doesn't set `\widowpenalty` at the right place, that is, *after* `\insert\footins{`, which is what my code does.

Note that the material for `\insert` is processed in a group, so the value of `\widowpenalty` will be restored as soon as the matching `}` is scanned.

Comment: In my document, printing `\the\widowpenalty` in the main text and in a footnote both gives the same redefined value. In an empty document however, your code achieves the desired effect.

Comment: There's a problem: How does the redefined (higher) widowpenalty is restored for the main text after the first footnote? In my examples, the default value of 150 remains after it is defined thus in the footnote.

Comment: The value of `\widowpenalty` is changed in the scope `\insert\footins{...}` and so its value does not influence the value outside footnotes and my experiments show this. Without details on your document and on how you do the setting/resetting, it's difficult to say more.

Comment: You're right, I had also tried an adapted solution with `\let\footnote\oldfootnote...` (without etoolbox) and in this case the change was not undone after the footnote. With your code I can reproduce the desired effect with a MWE. Maybe the problem with my document is that I redefine `\skip\footins`? I'll keep your solution in mind for future documents.

Comment: @johnny7 I guess that with your method you're setting the `\widowpenalty` at the wrong place, that is, outside `\insert\footins{...}`. Which won't work. I added some comments.

Comment: I see! I narrowed down the problem in my document: `\usepackage{scrextend}` (of Komascript) breaks your solution. Any ideas?

Comment: @johnny7 In that case, the command to patch should be `\scr@saved@footnotetext`.